# problema con header location en dos url diferentes

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo el siguiente codigo

```
require('db.php');

if($_POST['id']);        
{ 
    for($i=0; $i<count($_POST['id']); $i++) 
    {

        $msjn=$_POST['mensaje'];
        $idfoto=$_POST['id'];
        $nomb=$_POST['nombre'];
        $r1=$_POST['responsable1'];
        $r2=$_POST['responsable2'];
        $esms=$_POST['estado_sms'];
        $conc=$_POST['concepto'];
        $fc=$_POST['fecha'];
        $d=$_POST['dia'];
        $m=$_POST['mes'];
        $an=$_POST['ano'];
        $cm=$_POST['cm'];

        $nmob=$_POST['mobile'];

        $query="INSERT INTO sms (id, nombre, responsable1, responsable2, estado_sms, concepto, fecha, mobile, mensaje, dia, mes, ano) VALUES ('".$idfoto[$i]."','".$nomb[$i]."','".$r1[$i]."','".$r2[$i]."','".$esms[$i]."','".$conc."','".$fc[$i]."','".$nmob[$i]."','".$msjn."','".$d."','".$m."','".$an."')"; 
        $r = $conexion->query($query);


        //envio del sms 
        $umob=implode($nmob);
        header("Location: https://sms.net/eapi/submission/send_sms/2/2.0?username=".$usuario."&password=".$pass."&message=".$msjn."&msisdn=".$umob."".$telf."");

        //Aqui debe redireccionarme a la pagina principal
        $alerta="Mensaje enviado Exitosamente!";
header("Location: ../pagina_principal.php?msj=".$alerta." ");   

    }   
}
```

EL problema que tengo es que si comento el segundo header("Location:..") el cual me redirecciona a la pagina principal, me redireciona perfectamente y me envia el sms , tambien inserta los datos.

Cuando utilizo los dos header("Location:..") Me inserta los datos correctamente y me redirecciona con el mensaje a la pagina principal pero no me emite el sms, como puedo lograr enviar estos dos header correctamente.

Comment: Te sobra un `;` en `if($_POST['id']);`

Answer (score 1):

por que no pruebas guardando el formulario por ajax y despues que lo halla guardado mandas el mensaje,algo así:

```js
<!-- language: lang-js -->

    <script>
    ("#insertar").click(){
         var msjn=$('#mensaje').val();
         var idfoto=$('#id').val();
         ...
         ...
         ...
         var s={'mensaje'=>msjn,'id'=>idfoto,....} 
         $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "https://sms.net/eapi/submission/send_sms/2/2.0",
                  data:s,
                  contentType: "text/plain; charset=UTF-8",
                  dataType: "text",                         
                  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {   },
                  success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        var alerta="Mensaje enviado Exitosamente!";
                        var s1="{'msj':alerta}"
                        $.ajax({
                             type: "POST",
                             url: "../pagina_principal.php",
                             data:s1,
                             contentType:"text/plain; charset=UTF-8",
                             dataType: "text",                         
                             error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)                                           {},
                             success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {}                        
                                    }); 

                                   }                        
         }); 
    }

    <script>

<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <form>
    ....
    <button id="insertar">..</button>
    </form>
```

---

por supuesto para eso usa un for,por ejemplo:

```js
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){  
    var a=arr[i]; 
    var s="{'id'=>a.id,'nombre'=>a.nombre}";
    $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "..",
              data:s,
              contentType:"text/plain; charset=UTF-8",
              dataType: "text",                         
              error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){},                                 
              success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {}                        
          }); 
}
```

Comment: Hola @Omar Miranda Gracias por tu respuesta , voy a probar tu sugerencia, pero estoy enviando array una x cantidad de teléfonos, esta solución me permite hacerlo de igual forma?

Answer (score -1):

No lo puedes hacer usando dos `header("Location...")`. El primer request tienes que hacerlo no cambiando la ubicación del browser, sino internamente.

Por la manera como lo tienes pareciera ser una petición GET, por lo que la variante más fácil que puedes probar es:

```
$envio = file_get_contents("https://sms.net/eapi/submission/send_sms/2/2.0?username=".$usuario."&password=".$pass."&message=".$msjn."&msisdn=".$umob.$telf);

$alerta="Mensaje enviado Exitosamente!";
header("Location: ../pagina_principal.php?msj=".$alerta." ");
```

Pero en realidad existen maneras más elegantes de hacerlo. Por ejemplo usando [curl](http://php.net/manual/es/book.curl.php) o [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/), que te permitirían saber si la petición al servicio de SMS retornó una cabecera 200 (éxito) o una cabecera de error. En este momento tienes tu mensaje de éxito en duro y no condicionado a lo que el servicio de SMS responda.

Comment: También podría hacerlo por ajax en lugar de hacerlo por get

Comment: eso implicaría hacer un llamado al backend para la inserción más otro llamado directo al servicio de SMS para enviar el mensaje. Y luego redirigir a la portada condicionado a que ambos requests se cumplan. Creo que lo más sano es una respuesta que funcione con el mínimo de intervención para que esto no se convierta en un hilo de comentarios gigante de prueba y error.

Comment: Hola @amenadiel muchas gracias por tu respuesta, intente tu solución me arrojo un erro 500 por la palabra var , al quirarla me duro mucho al cargar me hizo la inserción de datos y dirección a pagina principal pero no el envio del sms

Comment: @AlexanderQuiroz Tenía ese error y además dos puntos concatenando la URL del SMS. Por favor pruébalo ahora.

Comment: hermano nuevamente gracias @amenadiel pero de igual manera no me realizo el envio del sms

Comment: Está es la mejor respuesta. Además de que no se deben hacer 2 redirecciones, debria de haber un `die();` despues de la llamada `header()`, para evitar que continue. El que no se envíe el SMS a de ser por alguna otra razón, y para detectar el motivo deberían de procesar la respuesta.